# How to autoload a repository in composer which does not follow PSR-0 or PSR-4?

Tags: php, repository, composer-php, psr-0

So, I'm trying to use [jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk](https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk), but it follows no standards whatsoever and does not have a repository available, so I've had to manually define it myself in my `composer.json` file:

```
"repositories" : [{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "origin/master"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": ["reddit-php-sdk/", "/", "reddit.php", "config.php"]
        }
    }
}],
```

Directory structure in `vendor/` here:

[image]

However, when I then run `composer dump-autoload`, the classes in this project are not autoloaded, and don't appear in any of the `autoload_*.php` composer files. This means I of course get a `"Class 'reddit' not found"` error whenever I try and use it.

Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up forking the project myself, but it turns out the original project is broken anyway.

Comment: Want to link your fork?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Composer's `file` [autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files).

```
{
"autoload": {
    "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

However, that's more geared towards helper function files and I've not tried it with a Class file (although there's no reason it shouldn't work).

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but this is not working. Even did a full composer reinstall of all my packages.